# Diffeomorphism to tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I had to solve the following problem.

Let $M$ be a differenciable $m$-manifold, which admits a global base of differianciable vector fields $\{X_1,\ldots,X_m\}$. This means $\{X_1(p),\ldots,X_m(p)\}$ is a base of $T_pM$ for all $p\in M$. Consider the map $\Psi:M\times\mathcal{R}^m\rightarrow TM$, given by

$\Psi(x,(v^1,\ldots,v^m))=\sum_{i=1}^mv^i X_i(x),\quad\text{para}\quad x\in M  \quad\text{y}\quad (v^1,\ldots,v^m)\in\mathcal{R}^m.$

Show that $\Psi$ is a diffeomorphism.

First $\Psi$ is bijective and obviously differenciable. 
Because $\{X_1(p),\ldots,X_m(p)\}$ is a basis for all $p$ we can write an element of $TM$ as $Y_p=\sum y^iX_i(p)$. Define the map $\phi:TM\rightarrow M\times\mathcal{R}^m$ by

$\phi(Y)=\phi(\sum y^iX_i(p))=(p,y)$ with $y=(y^1,\ldots,y^m)\in\mathcal{R}^m$.

It follows that

$\phi\circ\Psi(p,v)=(p,v)=id_{M\times\mathcal{R}^m}$

$\Psi\circ\phi(Y_p)=Y_p=id_{TM}$

so that $\phi=\Psi^{-1}$.

Now my questions:
1. Is this all right till here?
2. This is probably easy, but I don't see it right now: Why is $\phi$ differenciable? If it were differencibale I would be done.

Thanks for your help

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $\Psi$ is smooth, bijective, and the differential has full rank everywhere (easy linear algebra), the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) guarantees $\phi = \Psi^{-1}$ is differentiable.